# $A_\alpha$ $\subset$ $X$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$($\cap_\alpha A_\alpha$) $\subset$ ($\cap_\alpha f$ ($A_\alpha$))

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

$f$:$X$$\rightarrow$$Y$

Claim: $\forall$ $\alpha$$\in$$A$:  $A$$_\alpha$ $\subset$ $X$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$($\cap$$_\alpha$$A$$_\alpha$) $\subset$ ($\cap$$_\alpha$ $f$ ($A$$_\alpha$)

Proof: Assume the claim is incorrect, thus applies $f$($\cap$$_\alpha$$A$$_\alpha$) $\not\subset$ ($\cap$$_\alpha$ $f$ ($A$$_\alpha$)

Consider A:= {$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$} such that

$A_{x1}$=$A_{x2}$:= {$x_1$, $x_2$}  $A_{x3}$:={$x_2$,$x_3$}

And $f$ such that
$f$($x_1$)= $y_1$ ,  $f$($x_2$)= $y_2$ ,  $f$($x_3$)= $y_1$

Follows: $f$($A_{x1}$) $\cap $ $f$($A_{x2}$) $\cap $$f$($A_{x3}$) = {$y_1$,$y_2$}

But $f$($A_{x1}$$\cap $$A_{x2}$$\cap $$A_{x3}$) = $f$($x_2$)={$y_2$}

$\unicode{x21af}$

My questions:

1) is my proof argumentation correct?

2) Is my understanding of the indexset $A_\alpha$ $\alpha$ $\in$ A  correct as used by the example above?

3) I have tried to solve this question with direct proof however I failed. Can someone offer some insights? (I was supposing an y out of the left set and trying the reach the right set VIA definitions)

4) I fail to see the importance of the left side of the equation  $A$$_\alpha$ $\subset$ $X$ since it does not appear in my argumentation at any point.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

1) You have shown an example that the inclusion can be strict. You still need to prove it, that means show that every element of $f( \bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha)$ is also an element of $\bigcap_\alpha f(A_\alpha)$.

2) In your example, your $A_\alpha$'s are subsets of the index set $A$, which of course can happen, but in principle the index set can be completely unrelated to the set $X$, for example $A = \{1,2,3\}$.

3) Your proof of the possibility of strictness of the inclusion is actually a proof by example, if you delete the first sentence of the proof you actually change nothing.

4) It tells you that the sets $A_\alpha$'s are subsets of the same set $X$ on which $f$ is defined. It is rather a preparation that assumption.

Comment: 1) I see now my mistake. I proved that the other inclusion does not apply. But how can I prove that the first one does apply? 

2) $A$$\subset$ $X$ and $\alpha$$\in$$A$ Doesn't it mean that $\alpha$ $\in$$X$? Shouldn't this always mean that an index set of this forum is always a subset from it's bigger set?


BTW: if I say suppose the claim isn't true thus $f$($\cap$$_\alpha$$A$$_\alpha$) $\not\subset$ ($\cap$$_\alpha$ $f$ ($A$$_\alpha$)

with the example i've given above follows that the claim is incorrect thus the original claim must apply

Comment: Here is why I couldn't go on with the direct proof.


Let $y$ $\in$ $f$($\cap$$_\alpha$$A$$_\alpha$)

Then after definition of a functions image ( which is $f(K)$ := {$y\in Y | \exists k \in K ,with f(k)=y $} )

$\Leftrightarrow$  $\exists$ $x$$\in$ $\cap$$_\alpha$$A$$_\alpha$ : $f(x)$=$y$

However that is not the case in the $\Leftarrow$ direction.

Consider the example above for the case.

But i am not sure if i can just right $\Rightarrow$ since after definition there sould be equality.

Can you help me here?

Comment: You have that $A_\alpha \subset X$ not $A \subset X$. It would probably be less confusing if you name the sets $X_\alpha$ rather than $A_\alpha$.

Also I can't comment your answer since my rep is too low, but your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have reached new insights about my question.

New proof (direct)

Let $y \in f(\cap_\alpha A_\alpha) $

$\Leftrightarrow \exists x \in \cap_\alpha A_\alpha : f(x) =y $

$\Leftrightarrow \exists x \in A_\alpha \forall \alpha \in A : f(x) =y $

Let $x_0$ be such $x$. Thus $x_0 \in A_\alpha \forall \alpha $ 
$\Rightarrow y\in f(A_\alpha) \forall \alpha $
$\Rightarrow y \in \cap_\alpha f(A_\alpha) $

What do you guys think of this? also can you give your thoughts to the previous comment since apparently that person isn't checking this topic.